# Creating a custom post type - want to add an alert for user

Tags: custom-post-types

My question is easy but I can't find any answers via Google or Stackexchange.

I've created a custom post type and everything's going great so far. I'd like to make it so that when the user is creating a new item, they see a yellow box at the top alerting them of something. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to combine the `save_post hook` ([codex link here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)) and the `admin_notices` hook ([codex link here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices)). I know link only answers are normally not acceptable, but I think you should start with reading some codex stuff :-). Hope this helps!